# Change water colour on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, style

I have downloaded this website template/theme: http://steelthemes.com/demo/html/indusrty-press/

When I look at the code I see this:

```
<section class="google-map-area">
    <div 
      class="google-map" 
      id="home-google-map" 
      data-map-lat="40.712784" 
      data-map-lng="-74.005941" 
      data-icon-path="img/resources/map-marker.png"
      data-map-title="Brooklyn, New York, United Kingdom"
      data-map-zoom="12"
      data-markers='{
                "marker-1": [40.712784, -74.005941, "<h4>Personal Trainning Camp</h4><p>228 Park Ave S, New York, UK</p>"]
            }'>
     </div>
</section>
```

They also include `gmaps.js`

Neither seem to define the colour (or any other colour).  How are they achieving this?

Is there a way to easily download the lat/long for multiple markers from my Google My Maps?

Comment: what link URL is that? I don't see a theme...

Comment: It is a website template/theme.  That whole page.  Towards the bottom is the Google Maps part which has yellow water which fits right in with the template.

Comment: it is using Google Map Styles https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: @Eoin gotcha - writing up a solution now...

Comment: the script that styles the map is http://steelthemes.com/demo/html/indusrty-press/js/map-helper.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file being used is the map-helper.js

http://steelthemes.com/demo/html/indusrty-press/js/map-helper.js

There are several ways to generate this, including:

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

From there, you can use style in a .js file

```
function loadgbasemap() {

    /*google styled basemap*/
    var styled = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
        zIndex: 200,
        type : 'roadmap',
        styles : [{
            "featureType" : "water",
            "elementType" : "geometry",
            "stylers" : [{
                "color" : "#b6d9ff"
            }, {
                "lightness" : 17
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType" : "landscape",
            "elementType" : "geometry",
            "stylers" : [{
                "color" : "#f5f5f5"
            }, {
                "lightness" : 20
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType" : "road.highway",
            "elementType" : "geometry.fill",
            "stylers" : [{

   etc. etc. etc.
```

Then call it in your application:

```
<script src="gmap/gmapbase.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://mapkit.io/editor has Theme Editor and Export Tool to quickly get a new theme up and running too.